# Convergence of Fourier series of an integrable function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Show that if the Fourier series of an integrable function $f$ converges a.e., then it converges
to $f$ a.e.

To solve this problem I have showed that if $F_n$ is Frejer kernel then Cesaro means $f*Fn$ of Fourier series of integrable function $f$   (i.e $L^1(S^1)$ function) converges almost everywhere to a function $g$ , also we know that $L^1$ norm $$\lim_{n\to\infty}||f*F_n-f||_1=0$$.

Now I need to show that $g$ is integrable and $L^1$ norm $||f-g||_1=0$, please help me to solve this.

Comment: Since the Cesaro means are averages of the partial sums, if the series converges to $g(x)$ at $x$ then $F_n*f(x)\to g(x)$. But we know that $F_n\to f$ almost everwhere; hence $f=g$ ae.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Dvaid, can you please tell me how $F_n$ tend to $f$ a.e!

Comment: This is a standard result in Fourier analysis. look for "almost-everywhere summability"